# Exclusion and inclusion criteria for healthy controls in colorectal cancer study

Tags: human-biology, cancer

I'm working on colorectal cancer, and I'm facing a problem in the sampling step, I can't figure out how to choose healthy subjects. In the literature, I've found many criteria that are different and sometimes not clear or the author don't mention how he chooses his control samples.
PS: I'll collect stool samples, not tissues.

Comment: Welcome to the world of poorly designed studies. Not saying yours is or will be, just  saying the confusion you feel isn't unwarranted. I wish I could offer you a solution.

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com

Comment: Providing more details (e.g. what you are going to study, how you are planning to do it, how others have done it) would invite good answers to this question. Also I agree with @anongoodnurse: selecting controls for a case-control study can be challenging. (There is a nice section on this in a textbook called  'Gordis Epidemiology', that might help. https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Xwl0DwAAQBAJ)